# Egg dropping problem utilising binomial coefficient and Luca's Theorem

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Currently I'm solving an interesting performance variant of the [egg dropping problem](https://brilliant.org/wiki/egg-dropping/) from codewars for which I need your help. The following equation is given:
\begin{equation}
f(d,n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}{d \choose i}
\end{equation}

- d represent the number of tries
- n represents the number of eggs

$f(d,n)$ calculates the maximum skyscrapper height (in floors), in which it is guaranteed to find an exactly maximal floor from which an egg won't crack.

---

**Now the twist:**
Calculates the maximum skyscrapper height (in floors), in which it is guaranteed to find an exactly maximal floor from which an egg won't crack. But this time:

- d $\leq 100000$ and n $\leq 800000$

or

- $d \leq 2^{200}$ and n $ \leq 3000$

Due to these huge numbers it is required to calculate the result $\mod 998244353 $. This gives us the following formula:

\begin{equation}
f(d,n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}{d \choose i} \mod 998244353
\end{equation}

Now we can utilise the [Lucas Theorem](https://brilliant.org/wiki/lucas-theorem/) in order to speed up the calculation:
\begin{align*}
    \sum_{i=1}^{n}{d \choose i} \equiv \sum_{i=1}^{n} \prod_{j=0}^{k} {d_{j} \choose i_{j}} \mod 998244353
\end{align*}

This will only improve computation performance if $d > 998244353 $ for example:

- $n=2$
- $d=160693804425899027554196$

\begin{align}
\textstyle f(d,n) &\equiv {161259 \choose 0} * {536078175 \choose 0} * {736559690 \choose 1} + {161259 \choose 0} * {536078175 \choose 0} * {736559690 \choose 2} \mod 998244353 \\
&\equiv {736559690 \choose 1} + {736559690 \choose 2} \mod 998244353
\end{align}
This reduces the binomial coefficient, however the computational costs are still way too high. **Do you have any hints on how to speed up computation ?**

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The binomial costs are trivial.  ${x \choose 1} = x$ and ${x \choose 2} = x (x-1)/2$.

So your final computation took .000029 seconds on a Mac laptop.

Comment: Yes for this specific case you are right. But what if n=3000  and d=736559690? Then the computational costs explode.